# All content disabled until value in textbox, but button being enabled when clicking in the checkboxlist even when textbox has no value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkboxlist

Newbie in asp.net
I have a asp.net application with some textboxes and checkboxlist

All content disabled until value in textbox, but button being enabled when clicking in the checkboxlist even when textbox has no value

How can i prevent the button from being enabled when clicking in checkboxlist

this is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" style="background-color: #fbfcfc">
    function CheckCheck() {
        
        var chkBoxList = document.getElementById('<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID %>');
        var chkBoxCount = chkBoxList.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var btn = document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>');
        var i = 0;
        var tot = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < chkBoxCount.length; i++) {
            if (chkBoxCount[i].checked) {
                tot = tot + 1;
            }
        }

        if (tot > 2) {
            alert('You can only pick 2 games'); btn.disabled = true;
        } 
        else {
            btn.disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableBtn() {
        var btn = document.getElementById("<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>");
        document.getElementById('<%=Nickname.ClientID%>').disabled = true;

        var controls = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID%>").getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++)
            controls[i].disabled = true;

        btn.disabled = true;


    }

</script>

<script>
    function check(obj) {
      if (obj.value.trim() != "") {
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = false;
      //      document.getElementById("Panel1").disabled = false;

          document.getElementById('<%=Nickname.ClientID%>').disabled = false;

          var controls = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID%>").getElementsByTagName("input");

          for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++)
              controls[i].disabled = false;


          

            }

        }
</script>
```

This is where i call the javascript

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" TabStop="false" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="10" Width="420px" onclick="javascript:CheckCheck();" Font-Size="X-Large">

 <body id="body" class="" onload="javascript:disableBtn();">

<asp:TextBox ID="IDCard" onblur="return check(this);" TabIndex="1" TabStop="true" runat="server" OnTextChanged="ID_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Wrap="False" Width="151px" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Height="41px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: How does these functions get called? By event listeners? Show how you subscribe to events.

Comment: And why do you have a `style` on the first `script` tag? It does not make sense.

Comment: <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" TabStop="false" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="10" Width="420px" onclick="javascript:CheckCheck();" Font-Size="X-Large">

<body id="body" class="" onload="javascript:disableBtn();">

<asp:TextBox ID="IDCard" onblur="return check(this);" TabIndex="1" TabStop="true" runat="server" OnTextChanged="ID_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Wrap="False" Width="151px" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Height="41px"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Please EDIT your question to include your code.